# Spectroscopic methods for quantifying peptides/proteins with or without Tryptophan or Tyrosine content

Tags: proteins, lab-techniques, uv, spectroscopy

I have several peptides (20-50 amino acids long)  which I want to quantify the solubility/concentration in a solvent at certain temperature and pH.

These peptides may or may not contain Tryptophan or Tyrosine (aromatic residues) in them.
What's the preferred quantification method for it?

I came to UV-Vis method (e.g. [**NanoDrop**](https://www.thermofisher.com/jp/en/home/industrial/spectroscopy-elemental-isotope-analysis/molecular-spectroscopy/ultraviolet-visible-visible-spectrophotometry-uv-vis-vis/uv-vis-vis-instruments/nanodrop-microvolume-spectrophotometers/nanodrop-protein-quantification.html)) and Fluorescence method (e.g. **[Qubit](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/Q33211)**).
Do those methods strictly require the presence of Tryptophan or Tyrosine?

Comment: I can’t write a full answer right now, but absorbance at 280 nm requires aromatic amino acids (tryptophan, tyrosine, phenylalanine) and/or cystine. If these residues are not present, you could potentially label your peptides with some fluorophore. Alternatively, the peptide bond itself absorbs at 214 nm. You can also look into assays like BCA.

Comment: @canadianer does *fluoresence* method also require aromatic residues?

Comment: If you’re just looking at intrinsic fluorescence of the peptide, then yes. If you are able to specifically label the peptide with some fluorophore, then no.

Comment: I suspect, but don’t know for sure, that the Qubit assay you linked to won’t work well for unstructured peptides. Thermo also sells a Qubit BR assay that apparently reacts with amino groups and therefore should work with peptides. You should ask them directly to be sure.

Comment: The A280 value is mainly due to Trp content but if the sequence is known, you can calculate the extinction coefficient very accurately. In addition, you can fully recover the sample after an A280 measurement, whereas fluorescent/colorimeteric methods require some sample loss. I give the key refs below, but this [old answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/55363/1136) (mine) may be of interest?

Comment: [Protein volumes and hydration effects. The calculations of partial specific volumes, neutron scattering matchpoints and 280-nm absorption coefficients for proteins and glycoproteins from amino acid sequences](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3709531/)

Comment: [Calculation of protein extinction coefficients from amino acid sequence data](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2610349/)

Answer (score 4):

**I think it would not be a problem if you use NanoDrop for your measurements. But there are better options if using UV-Vis is not a strict rule. Alternatively, Qubit itself doesn't have any issues since their reagents do not get interfered by aromatics.**

As I understood from your description, you preferred using UV-Vis method, which uses wavelengths around 100-400 nm (UV-A 315-400 nm, UV-B 280-315 nm, UVC 100-280 nm). **ThermoFischer provides two options for UV-band measurement using NanoDrop** ([Table 1 of NanoDrop Protein Quantification page](https://www.thermofisher.com/id/en/home/industrial/spectroscopy-elemental-isotope-analysis/molecular-spectroscopy/ultraviolet-visible-visible-spectrophotometry-uv-vis-vis/uv-vis-vis-instruments/nanodrop-microvolume-spectrophotometers/nanodrop-protein-quantification.html)), **A280 and A205**.

The usual A280 method is what you are concerned about, since its absorbance behaviour is strictly linked to tryptophan, tyrosine, and some disulfide bonds. This limits A280 only to protein samples with those residues. To avoid this issue, [Anthis and Clore](https://doi.org/10.1002/pro.2253) has developed a method of using 205 nm UV-band instead of 280 nm with promising results. You can choose the 205 nm-band method in the NanoDrop settings.

However, if I am not limited to measuring in UV-band, I would personally use Pierce 660 nm colorimetry method to measure my samples. [This paper by Antharavally et. al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ab.2008.11.024) describes its flexibility on several substances (detergents, buffers, etc.) and its concentration which might suit your treatments. It is also available in NanoDrop settings, even with much greater sensitivity than both UV-Vis methods.

Speaking of Qubit, their [BR (Broad-Range) Protein Assays](https://www.thermofisher.com/document-connect/document-connect.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.thermofisher.com%2FTFS-Assets%2FLSG%2Fmanuals%2FMAN0024790_QubitBR_ProteinAssay_UG.pdf) are based on reagents reacting to N-terminals of proteins, not aromatic residues. There should not be a problem for any protein strands.

Comment: thanks so much. How reliable is *Anthis and Clore* method? Also for peptide that contain aromatic can be used? 
With their tool https://spin.niddk.nih.gov/clore/ does that mean we can just skip performing measurement with Nandrop/Qubit?

Comment: Also, I only have Qubit 3.0 and Flex,  AFAIK I can't use BR. But can I use standard [Protein Assays](https://bit.ly/39p0fSI)? Does it have any aromatic residue restriction?s

Comment: I need to clarify that Anthis and Clore's method of using 205 nm band is also available in the NanoDrop options.

ThermoFischer Protein Assays are quite robust on general protein strands. I don't remember their fluorophores are inhibited by aromatic residues....